# Creating a Draggable Widget System

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm looking to create a widget system, somewhat like what WordPress has.
Please suggest what script would be the best for this. I've planned to use jQuery UI for this, but would like to listen to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Go with Jquery.  We've implemented an entire pageflakes-esque drag/droppable widget system on our customizable homepage [Faxo Search](http://faxo.com/).  We couldn't be more pleased with jquery and jquery UI.  We looked at other libraries and decided jquery had the largest potential.  It's extremely expressive and the code is tight and efficient.  We actually migrated from Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) has a decent [drag and drop](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/draggable) implementation. It's based on [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) which has a pretty good community.

jQuery's *does* seem to be a bit larger and a more active as of late so you may want to stick with its [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) library.